# Grunt watch task is not starting until the first output to console

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-express

My task configuration works fine but I have annoying issue where the watch task does not start to monitor unless I refresh a page or add a line for console output. So normally I am supposed to get:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

But I don't get it until some output goes to the console.

Is it a bug?

My config is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: '\n\n'
            },
            dev: {
                src: ['ng_app/app.js', 'ng_app/**/*.js'],
                dest: 'public/js/app.js'
            }
        },
        less: {
                dev: {
                    files: [
                        {
                            expand: true,
                            cwd: 'styles',
                            src: ['*.less', '!mixins.less', '!var.less'],
                            dest: 'public/css/',
                            ext: '.css'
                        },
                        {
                            expand: true,
                            cwd: 'styles/views',
                            src: ['*.less'],
                            dest: 'public/css/views',
                            ext: '.css'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            express: {
                dev: {
                    options: {
                        script: 'bin/www'
                    }
                }
            },
            watch: {
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                },
                express: {
                    files:  ['**/*.js'],
                    tasks:  ['express:dev'],
                    options: {
                        spawn: false
                    }
                },
                less: {
                    files: ['styles/**/*.less'],
                    tasks: ['less'],
                    options: {
                        livereload: false
                    }
                },
                concat: {
                    files:  ['ng_app/**/*.js'],
                    tasks: ['concat'],
                    options: {
                        livereload: false
                    }
                }
            }
      });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'less']);
    grunt.registerTask('server', [ 'express:dev', 'watch' ]);
};
```

Comment: Can you paste your task config?

Comment: Are you aware that watch only runs when a file changes in the time grunt watch is running? The initial processing is not done by watch, watch only starts processing when grunt is running watch and you change a file in that time.

Comment: In this case I get something like this:

>> File "ng_app\directives\stxOptionSwitch.js" changed.
Running "concat:dev" (concat) task
File public/js/app.js created.

But if file is changed before any output to the console then it does nothing.

Comment: When I add console.log('Something') then the "watch task" launching. I suspect the problem in grunt-express-server (or Express.js itself) where the startup process is stopped at some point and not proceeding to the point of starting watch until some event (like logging to console) happens.